# JavaFX application crashes on Mac when the user switch from it to another app in full screen mode

Tags: java, javafx, modal-dialog

I don't understand what it can be. For this reason I don't know where to get my hands.

I'm using:

- Java SE 1.8
- JavaFX for the user interface

The condition in which the application crashes:

- The app is showing a modal:

```
Stage dialog = new Stage();
dialog.setScene(new Scene(root));
dialog.initOwner(loader.getController());
dialog.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL); 
dialog.showAndWait();
```

- The user switches from this app to another app opened in full screen.

This is what happens when the error occurs:

1. The application is closed
2. An error appears in the console (I'm pretty sure it's not a java exception)

[image: screenshot]

What is the problem? 
Does it happen only on Mac?
How can I solve it?

Comment: no screenshots of text please, they are unreadable..

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by updating to JavaFX 14.
I suppose it was a bug of the library.